# use ansible-vault to encrypt multiple files at once

Tags: security, encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

I am using the following structure to separate my `host_vars` into plaintext and encrypted

```
ansible
├── ansible.cfg
├── host_vars
│   ├── host1
│   │   ├── vars
│   │   └── vault
│   └── host2
│       ├── vars
│       └── vault
├── inventory
├── site.yaml
└── vars
    └── ansible_vars.yaml
```

Is there a way, using `ansible-vault` to encrypt both files named `vault` or do I have to do them one by one?

Just asking since there are more to come, e.g. in future directories of `group_vars` etc.

I know this works

```
ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/host1/vault host_vars/host2/vault
```

just asking whether there is a more elegant / quick solution

Comment: Use the expansion capacities of your shell: `ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/*/vault`?

Comment: thanks, nice idea. if you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities gives by [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

Here are two that would be interesting in your case:

- The asterisk `*` expansion, that is used as a wildcard.
  Which means that `host_vars/*/vault` would match both `host_vars/host1/vault` and `host_vars/host2/vault` but any other in the future, too.
- Mind that, if, in the future, you have a more complex folder hierarchy `host_vars/*/vault` will only match one folder level (e.g. it won't match `host_vars/level1/host1/vault`), but multiple folder levels can be achieved with a double asterisk (actually named *globstar*): `host_vars/**/vault`, will match
  `host_vars/host1/vault` as well as `host_vars/level1/host1/vault`
- The [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), on the other hands offer a more granular set of possibilities, for examples, if I have hosts names after the distributions like `RedHat[1..5]`, `Ubuntu[1..5]` and `Debian[1..5]`, I could target only the Debian and RedHat ones via `host_vars/{Ubuntu*,RedHat*}/vault`.
  Or only target the three first of them both with `host_vars/{Ubuntu{1..3},RedHat{1..3}}/vault`, or the three first of them all via `host_vars/*{1..3}/vault`

As a more practical example, if you where to handle SE via Ansible and would like to encrypt the the files for `*.stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com` but not `superuser.com` or any other Q&A having a specific domain name, given that the hosts are named as their DNS name, you could do

```sh
ansible-vault host_vars/{stackoverflow.com,*.stackexchange.com}/vault
```

Comment: Thank you for wildcard. Forgot about it. But the issue rises if by some reason Ansible throws the error at specific file. I just tried to rekey bunch of files and it turned out that there where some vault file placeholders which was not encrypted. So the script stops at first error. I tried to `|| true` but with no luck. Anyways, thank you for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will just throw in my quick super simple shell script which worked for my simple use case.
For sure it can be improved but I think it's a good starting point.
You could also utilize secret file via `--vault-password-file` parameter.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Choose the option:"
echo "(d) Decrypt all Ansible vault files"
echo "(e) Encrypt all Ansible vault files"
read option

function decrypt {
  ansible-vault decrypt --ask-vault-pass \
  ansible/*/environments/development/group_vars/*/vault.yaml \
  ansible/*/environments/development/host_vars/*/vault.yaml
}

function encrypt {
  ansible-vault encrypt --ask-vault-pass \
  ansible/*/environments/development/group_vars/*/vault.yaml \
  ansible/*/environments/development/host_vars/*/vault.yaml
}

case $option in
  d)
    decrypt
    ;;
  e)
    encrypt
    break
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Wrong option"
    ;;
esac
```